# how to keep js variable value accross multiple php pages

Tags: javascript

```
index.js // linked to all php files.
var pass;
console.log(pass); // undefined

$("#btn").click(function() {
    pass = "323";
    location.href = "test.php";
});
```

going to `test.php` console.log shows again `undefined`.
I need to keep `pass` value as `323` accross all pages, once it is estblished.

Comment: use cookies or localstorage or even sessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest method: Use `localStorage`.

If you only need to store strings:

```
var pass = localStorage.pass;

$("#btn").click(function() {
    pass = "323";
    localStorage.pass = pass;
    location.href = "test.php";
});
```

Or, notice that `localStorage` will change all things you store in into string. So if you wanted to store object, numbers, etc, you need `JSON.stringify`.

```
// index.js
if (localStorage.pass === undefined)
    localStorage.pass = "null";
var pass = JSON.parse(localStorage.pass);

$("#btn").click(function() {
    pass = "323";
    localStorage.pass = JSON.stringify(pass);
    location.href = "test.php";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the session to get your things work smoothly on all pages.

```
var pass;
console.log(pass); // undefined

$("#btn").click(function() {
   pass = "323";
   $.post('savesession.php','pass='+pass,function(){
       console.log("session saved");
       location.href = "test.php";
   });
});
```

**savesession.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
```

**anypage.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
```